# If $\int f(x)\phi(x)dx=0$ for every $\phi(x)$ that is smooth function compactly supported away from the origin then $f=0$

Tags: real-analysis

If $\int_\mathbb{R^d} f(x)\phi(x)dx=0$ for every $\phi(x)$ that is smooth function compactly supported away from the origin then $f=0$.

This looks very obvious but I don't know how to prove it. I was thinking of trying to come up with two functions that work as $\phi$ with a constant difference, say, $\phi_1$ and $\phi_1+c$ and subtract to get $\int cf=0$ then it is easy to conclude. But I don't know how to work toward this approach. Otherwise, I am unsure how to solve it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, please forget about my approach. It is very wrong

Comment: Are there any other conditions on $f$ that you know of? If $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ for any $x\neq 0$ then your hypothesis is satisfied but $f$ is not the zero function.

Comment: @Matthew pilling Oh thank you. Now I realize that $f$ is a smooth function away from the origin

Comment: In that case, have you considered a proof by contradiction? I'm not too familiar with the phrasing "compactly supported away from the origin," but if $f(x_0)\neq 0$ for some $x_0\in \mathbb{R^d}$, then by continuity you can find an open ball $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ containing $x_0$ such that $f(x)$ doesn't change its sign from $f(x_0)$ on $ U$. Try defining an appropriate $\phi$ that yields a non zero integral based off this. Many problems of this flavor follow this type of reasoning.

Comment: Is $f$ assumed continuous everywhere? Matthew's function seems to be "smooth away from the origin" (smooth on any neighborhood which doesn't intersect the origin).

Comment: (I accidentally upvoted your comment @jk001$-$ sorry!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions on $f$ are a little unclear, so I will assume that it is continuous (will edit accordingly otherwise). Now, suppose that $f$ is not identically zero, say $f(y)\neq 0.$ WLOG, suppose that $f(y)>0$. Extend this to a neighborhood $B_r(y)$ by continuity such that $\operatorname{dist}(0,B_r(y)):=\alpha>0$, where we are assuming WLOG that $y\neq 0$ (if $y=0,$ then take a point in this neighborhood, then take a neighborhood around that point which doesn't intersect the origin). Now, let $\phi
\in C_c^\infty$ be a smooth cutoff such that $\phi=1$ on $B_{r}(y)$ and $\phi=0$ outside of $B_{r+\alpha/2}(y).$ Then, $$\int \phi f=\int\limits_{B_r(y)}f(x)\, dx>0.$$

Really, we're just taking a smooth function which is $1$ on a small neighborhood which preserves the sign of $f$ and is equal to $0$ outside of a slightly larger neighborhood. Then, $\phi f=f$ on that neighborhood and integrating $f$ over the aforementioned neighborhood gives something positive.

Comment: Can you please explain why we have $\int \phi f=\int_{B_r(y)} f(x)dx$? Aren't we supposed to have inequality $\geq$ in place of =? But I see how it works. Thanks so much

Comment: @jk001 We're assuming that $f$ is only non-zero on the set $B_r(y),$ and $\phi=1$ on $B_r(y).$